# Coerciveness of this functional for $\|u\|\le 1+T$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $F\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Psi(u) =\int_0^T (1-\sqrt{1-u^2}) dt, u\in (0,1)$. Consider the functional
$$I(u)= \Psi(u) -\int_0^T F(u) dt,$$
where $u$ belongs to the space of Lipschitzian functions vanishing at $0$ and $T$ endowed with the norm $\|u\|=\|u\|_{\infty}+\|u^{\prime}\|_{\infty}$.
During the math class, the Professor said that if $\|u\|\le 1+T$, thus $I(u)<+\infty$.
On the other hand, if $\|u\|> 1+T$, it is $I(u)=+\infty$, which means that $I$ is coercive (my definition of coercive is that $I(u)\to +\infty$ as $\|u\|\to +\infty$).

My question is: why $\|u\|\le 1+T \implies I(u)<+\infty$?
I asked him but he answered that it follows by definition of $\Psi(u)$. Could someone please help me to understand why it is true?

Thank you in advance!